# Are duplicate questions deleted quickly on [meta]?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, meta

[This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350653/is-it-all-about-reputation) was recently asked.  It was marked as a duplicate and down-voted.  But now it has been deleted "for reasons of moderation."

Are duplicate questions deleted quickly on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)?

[image]

Comment: deleted by 3 20k-ers

Comment: The 4th bullet disappeared.  It was a troll attempt, that sealed its fate.

Answer (score 13):

Duplicates are useful to leave around when they're good signposts, or if there is useful information in the post itself.

Most duplicates (particularly on meta, but honestly on main sites as well) don't meet either of those conditions.  This tends to be all the more true the more commonly asked a question is.  Frequently asked questions tend to already have sufficient signposts to direct users to the canonical, and tend to have enough useful information on the existing posts that any answers posted to the duplicate, if there are any at all, are unlikely to add new information not accessible elsewhere.

Meta in particular tends to be flooded with a lot of *really* common duplicates.  There are posts like proposals that people be required to comment when downvoting that are asked on average of around once a day.  We don't need 5,000 of such proposals; they're just not adding *anything* useful, so they might as well get deleted.

Additionally, meta tends to be regularly frequented by lots of users with lots of moderation privileges (and relevantly, the interest to actually use them when it's appropriate, unlike main where many users aren't interested in site moderation) combined with a low enough frequency of questions that each one gets a lot of attention. This means that posts that merit moderation action on meta are much more likely to actually get it than posts on main; on main it often is difficult to get enough people to vote to close, or delete, even if such action is merited.

Answer (score 7):

I rather suspect it works like the main site: a duplicate is useful only to the extent that it acts as a useful sign post to the original question.

The case you cite does not. The title is bad, and the "question" is less a question and more of a rant. It's unlikely to help other people find the original, so it's best to chuck it.